# StackExchange notification icon badge slight bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Not sure if this is a gamedev-specific bug or a stackexchange bug, but the red "number of replies" badge doesn't completely cover the stackexchange logo.  It looks like it's a pixel or two too low.  It's super minor, but I thought I'd point it out.

[image]

This is on Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed this too. The fix should be in the next deployment.