# Little inbox notification number is slightly off its alignment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Almost the exact problem as in [this question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/stackexchange-notification-icon-badge-slight-bug)... but backwards! I'm seeing the number slightly *above* the line - again, in Chrome, on Windows.

[image: dang upstart kids]

Answer (score 2):

The fix will be in the next build